# jquery, select input field by class name, then work out it's value contains a special character

Tags: jquery, spring-mvc, input, jquery-selectors, textfield

what i need is....
I am currently working on a spring mvc project.
On one of my JSP I have a few input text fields:

```
<form:input path="objectPath1" class="cartonInputField"/>
<form:input path="objectPath2" class="cartonInputField"/>
<form:input path="objectPath3" class="cartonInputField"/>
<form:input path="objectPath4" class.="cartonInputField"/>
```

so when i select these input textfields by jquery, I wish to check see if each of them contains the term 'coma',   if this term 'coma'  found in anywhere,  replace it with empty string '', and do alert();

here is my attamp:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.cartonInputField').each(function(){
        var input = $(this);
        if (input.val().indexOf('coma') > -1) {
            $(this).val('');
            alert('must not contain term - coma!');
        }
    })

})
```

currently it does not work, i dont know what went wrong...
can anyone help me with code example. thanks

Comment: At what point do you want to validate the inputs? It seems pointless validating once on page load (which is what happens now). Also if multiples of "coma" exist, multiple alerts will get quite annoying. Please explain the overall aim.

Comment: Please correct your HTML too... you have a `class.=` on the 4th entry :)

Comment: checkout this on jsfiddle i have modified it a little bit http://jsfiddle.net/2qs0mcae/

Comment: I have a submit button, say <input type="submit" value="Save & Add" class="btn"/>,  what i want is...when i do click submit, validate each textfield value, if see 'coma', replace with empty string

Comment: @imran qasim: You are validating all the fields when any field changes... surely you just want to validate the field changed?

Comment: @seph: you need to catch the submit and validate then. There are plugins for validation. Why not use one of those?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to catch the form submit and put your checking code there.

**JSFiddle mockup:** http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/63xkgo7p/

Use a `filter` to see if *any* of the fields match that condition and only report the error once:

e.g.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('form').submit(function () {
        if ($(this).find('.cartonInputField').filter(function () {
            if ($(this).val().indexOf('coma') > -1) {
                $(this).val("");
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }).length) {
            alert('must not contain term - coma!');
            // Stop form submitting
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```